# Using Cookies in Blazor serverside to store session ID

Tags: c#, authentication, session, cookies, blazor

I have implemented storing Session ID using a class inherited from AuthenticationStateProvider. I stored the session in **ProtectedLocalStorage** but I understand that it is not the safest storage, providing possible access to XSS/CSRF attacks.
Instead, how can I implement safer storage using cookies?

This is how I solve Getting authentication state.

```cs
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var userSesstionStorageResult = await _sessionStorage.GetAsync<UserSession>("UserSession");
        var userSession = userSesstionStorageResult.Success ? userSesstionStorageResult.Value : null;
        if (userSession == null)
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.Username),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userSession.Role)
            }, "CustomAuth"));
        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
    }
}
```

Updating the state I solve likewise.